# The cohomology of the fiber of the Hopf fibration using the Eilenberg-Moore Spectral Sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

In John McCleary's book about Spectral Sequences he computes on p.248 the cohomology of the fiber of the Hopf fibration $S^3 \to S^7 \to S^4$ using the Eilenberg-Moore Spectral Sequence. He deduces that all differentials have to be isomorphisms since the fiber is a subspace of $S^7$. I don't understand this argument.